# How to prevent EF Core add-migration to open the text editor tab with the generated migration code?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Since a while in Visual Studio 2019, when I use Package Manager Window to execute `add-migration` command, after the migration code generated it automatically opens in a new text editor tab.

It may be an other Visual Studio 2019 setting, not specifically related with EF Core migration but I can not find out which one.

**Question**

Is there any way to prevent EF Core add-migration to open the text editor tab with the generated migration code?

Comment: I am not alone :-)